Image of the map that multiplies every matrix by a rank $r$ matrix
Motivated by this question, this question.
Let $n\ge m, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be fixed. Define
$$T_A:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}:= T_A(B)=AB^T.$$
Assume $rank(A)=r.$ How do I show that the maximum rank of a matrix in the image $Im(T_A)$ of $T_A$ is also r? So I just need to get one $B$ so that $AB$ has rank $r.$
When $r:=m,T_A$ is surjective, so the claim is proved. To show that $T_A$ is surjective, one can work with the right inverse, say $C,$ of $A:$ so there is a $C \in  \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ so that $AC^T=I_m.$ And then for any $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m},$ we can take $B:=D^TC$ so that $AB^T=AC^TD=I_mD=D.$
But if $r<m,T_A$ won't be surjective, as all matrices will have rank $\le r <m.$ But how do we show that the maximal rank of $r$ is attained by $T_A, i.e. \exists B$ so that $rank(AB^T)=r?$
The way I'm trying this is:
We can pick the $r\times r $ minor/submatrix $E$ of $A,$ that's invertible, and the $r \times k$ block submatrix $F$ that 'contains' $E$ as a submatrix, so $F,$ as a $m\times r$ matrix, has full rank $r,$ and then we can consider $G,$ the $k\times r$ right inverse of $F$. Now $rank(G)=r$ as well and $FG=I_r.$ I tried to complete $G$ by adding some rows to it, but it didn't quite go anywhere...hints appreciated! It seems we may need to work with the above $E$ or $F,$ and reduce the problem to one where the restricted linear map has full rank, but am a bit stuck here.
I just looked at this answer, and it seems the answer should be $B:=A?!$ So if $rank(A)=r, rank(AA^T)=r$ as well? :)

Yes $T_A(A)$ will do it, though this is specific to the field being $\mathbb R$.  If you were working over an arbitrary field you could construct $B$ using the Rank Normal Form of $A$

I finished to complete the answer, let me know what do you think :)

@FedericoFallucca: thank you  I'll read it carefully and let you know :)

@FedericoFallucca Thank you. I went througb it and found it helpful! Could you please explain this a bit more?
$m-null(AC)=m-(dim(\ker(A)\cap Im(C))+null(C))?$ i.e. why $null(AC)=dim(\ker(A)\cap Im(C))+null(C)?$ I get that it follows from rank-nullity theorem, but had a bit of trouble connecting the dots here. And I think there's a typo in the next step: it should be $m$ instead of $n?$

Nice that it was useful for you :). The the kernel of AC is the domain of the restriction map of C, so by null rank theorem we have that its dimension is the sum of the dimension of the kernel, that is exactly the kernel of C, and the dimension of the image, that we proved being Ker(A)\cap Im(C). I corrected the typo :)

Closely related: This earlier highly upvoted Question and Answers show that one can take $B=A$, so that $AB^T = AA^T$ has the same rank as $A$.

You are asking tho prove that given a $nxm$ matrix $C$, then $AC$ has rank less or equal than $A$.
You have to think what are the columns (or equivalently the rows) of a matrix $AC$ in general, $C=(c_{ij})_{1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}$. Indeed, you can observe that if we denote by $D_i$ the $i-th$ column of a matrix $D$, then
$$ (AC)_i= c_{1i}A_1+\dots c_{ni}A_n$$
But then the subspace generated by the columns of the matrix $AC$ is contained in the space generated by the columns of $A$:
$$ \langle (AC)_1, \dots,  (AC)_m\rangle \subseteq \langle A_1,\dots, A_n\rangle $$
By the definition of rank of a matrix, namely the dimension of the space generated by the columns of the matrix, this means
$$rk(AC)\leq rk(A).$$
You can also observe that the rank of $AC$ is always less or equal than the rank of $C$:
$$rk(AC)\leq \min(rk(A),rk(C)).$$
This means that in order to have $AC$ of rank $r$, then also  the rank of $C$ has to be $r$.
Moreover, you can prove the following:
Let us consider the natural restriction map $C_{|\ker(AC)}\colon \ker(AC)\to \mathbb R^n$, $x\mapsto Cx$. Then
$$\ker(A)\cap Im(C)=Im_C(\ker(AC))$$
and
$$rk(AC)=rk(C)-\dim(\ker(A)\cap Im(C)).$$
In particular, if $\ker(A)\cap Im(C))=\{0\}$, then the rank of $AC$ is the rank of $C$.
$\textbf{Proof.}$ The first set equality is easy to prove.
Finally, from null rank theorem on the restriction map $C$ we have
$$ rk(AC)=m-null(AC)=m-(dim(\ker(A)\cap Im(C))+null(C))=(m-null(C))-dim(\ker(A)\cap Im(C))=rk(C)-dim(\ker(A)\cap Im(C)).$$
Thus, you have to choose $C$ such that $C$ has rank $r$ equal to the rank of $A$ and and such that $\ker(A)\cap Im(C))=\{0\}$.
As you already observed, you can choose $C=A^t$ since the rank of $A^t$ is still $r$ and the intersection is zero. Indeed, if $AA^tx=0$, then
$$0=\langle AA^tx,x\rangle=\langle A^tx,A^tx\rangle=\vert \vert A^tx\vert \vert^2 \implies A^tx=0.$$
Note that the latter holds only if we are using the field $\mathbb  R$ but it fails on $\mathbb C$. For instance, if you take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1  &  i \end{pmatrix}$, then $AA^t=1-1=0$, that it has no rank $1$.

Thank you for your answer, but I'm trying to see when (for which $C$) the equality of ranks happens...? Or at least I need one such $C.$

Uh I am sorry, I did not understand. One second

so I'm really trying to show that the rank doesn't strictly decrease after multiplication, some matrices preserve the rank after multiplication.

Let $A\in \mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$ be fixed and let $T_A\colon \mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb R)\to \mathrm{Mat}_{m,m}(\mathbb R)$ be given by $T_A(B) = AB^{\intercal}$.
Claim 1: If $r(A)=\mathrm{rank}(A)=d$ then $r(T_A(B))\leq d$ for all $B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$.
The rank of a matrix is the dimension of its row or column space, but here it will be easier to work with the column space of $T_A(B)$.
Let $A = (\mathbf a_1|\ldots|\mathbf a_n)$ and $B=(\mathbf b_1|\ldots|\mathbf b_n)$, so that $\mathbf a_i$ and $\mathbf b_i$ are the i-th columns of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then if we write $(AB^{\intercal})_k$ for the $k$-th column of $T_A(B) = AB^{\intercal}$ ($1\leq k\leq m$), we have
$$
(AB^{\intercal})_k = \sum_{j=1}^n b_{kj}\mathbf a_j
$$
It follows that $\mathrm{Span}\{(AB^{\intercal})_k: 1\leq k\leq m\} \subseteq \mathrm{Span}\{\mathbf a_1,\ldots,\mathbf a_n\}$, and hence the inequality
$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{rank}(AB^{\intercal}) &= \dim(\mathrm{Span}\{(AB^{\intercal})_k: 1\leq k\leq m\} )\\
&=\dim(\text{Span}\{\sum_{j=1}^n b_{kj}\mathbf a_j: 1\leq k\leq m\})\\
&\leq \dim(\mathrm{Span}\{\mathbf a_1,\ldots, \mathbf a_n\})\\
&= \mathrm{rank}(A)
\end{split}
$$
follows immediately.
Moreover equality holds, i.e. $r(B^{\intercal}A)=r(A)$, when the columns of $AB^{\intercal}$ have the same span as the columns of $A$. One way to ensure this is as follows: the columns $\{\mathbf a_1,\ldots,\mathbf a_n\}$ of $A$ contain a subset $\{\mathbf a_{i_1},\ldots,\mathbf a_{i_d}\}$ which is a basis of the column spaces of $A$, where as above $d= r(A)$. (You can find such a subset by row reducing $A^{\intercal}$ and taking the columns of $A$ corresponding to leading $1$s in the reduced matrix). Let $B = (b_{ij})$ where $b_{ij} = 0$ unless $i=j=i_k$ for some $k$, $1\leq k\leq d$. Then $AB^{\intercal}$ has exactly $d$ nonzero columns $\{\mathbf a_{i_1},\ldots,\mathbf a_{i_d}\}$ and these by construction span the column spaces of $A$ so that $r(AB^{\intercal})=d=r(A)$
Note that there are, in general, many matrices $B$ for which $r(AB^{\intercal}) = r(A)$: In the diagram below, $\ker(A)= \{v \in \mathbb R^n: Av=0\}$ is the kernel of $A$.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb R^m @>B^{\intercal}>> \mathbb R^n @>A>> \mathbb R^m \\
@. @AAA @.\\
@. \ker(A) @.
\end{CD}
$$
Claim 2:
The composition $AB^{\intercal}$ has rank $d$ if and only if  $\mathrm{im}(B^{\intercal})+\ker(A)=\mathbb R^m$.
Proof: Clearly, if $\mathrm{im}(B^{\intercal})+\ker(A)=\mathbb R^n$, then $A(\mathbb R^n) = A(\mathrm{im}(B^{\intercal})) = \mathrm{im}(AB^{\intercal})$ so that $r(AB^{\intercal})=d$. Conversely, if $r(AB^{\intercal})=r(A)$, then since $\mathrm{im}(AB^{\intercal}) \subseteq \mathrm{im}(A)$, they are equal once they have the same dimension. But then $A^{-1}(A(\mathrm{im}(B^{\intercal})) = \mathrm{im}(B^{\intercal})+\ker(A)$ must be equal to $\mathbb R^n$ as required.
Thus if we pick a basis of the kernel of $A$, say $\{w_1,\ldots,w_{n-r}\}$ and extend it to a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_{n-r}, w_{n-r+1},\ldots,w_n\}$ then if $C$ is the matrix of the linear map $v\mapsto B^{\intercal}v$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^m$ and the basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ then $AB^{\intercal}$ has rank $d$ precisely when some $d\times d$ minor of $C$ obtained by taking the last $d$ rows of $C$ and any $d$ columns must be nonzero.   Now if $P$ denotes the change of basis matrix from the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ to the basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ then $C = PB^{\intercal}$, and hence it follows that the matrices $B$ for which $AB^{\intercal}$ has rank $r$ are an open dense subset of $\mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$ (given by the locus where at least one of the relevant minors of $PB^{\intercal}$ does not vanish, and those minors are polynomial functions in the matrix entries of $B$).
The OP notes that another possibility for a $B$ with $r(AB^{\intercal})=r(A)$ is $B=A$. You can check that this choice for $B$ works by using the criterion $\mathrm{im}(A^{\intercal})+\ker(A)=\mathbb R^n$.  Since $r(A)=r(A^{\intercal})$, by rank-nullity it suffices to show that $\mathrm{im}(A^{\intercal})\cap \ker(A)=\{0\}$.
Suppose that $A^{\intercal}v \in \ker(A)$. Then $AA^{\intercal}v =0$, and hence
$$
0=v^\intercal AA^{\intercal}v=(A^{\intercal}v)^{\intercal}(A^{\intercal}v) = \|A^{\intercal}v\|^2,
$$
so that $A^{\intercal}v$ has length zero, and hence $A^{\intercal}v =0$. Thus it follows that $\ker(A)\cap \mathrm{im}(A^{\intercal})= \{0\}$ as required.

If $A=0$ then there is nothing to prove. So let $\text{rank}(A) = r > 0$. By rank factorization (or by SVD) there is a $m \times r$ matrix $U$ and an $n \times r$ matrix $V$, both of rank $r$ such that $A=UV^T$. Note the $r \times r$ matrix $V^TV$ is invertible (because it is an $r \times r$ matrix of rank $r$). Choose $B^T = V(V^TV)^{-1}U^T$. Then, $AB^T =UU^T$. Since $\text{rank}(UU^T) = \text{rank}(U) = r$ we are done.
If you know about the Moore-Penrose inverse, you can choose $B^T$ to be the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$
